# State and country on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist

I have a `Visualforce Page` which creates an `Account` based on data given by user, such as `Name`, `Phone`, and other details. I would like to include state and country too. I am using

```
<apex:inputfield value ="{!customobject__c.account__r.billingcountrycode}">
```

This tag displays the country picklist on the page. When I select a value and save it, the `Account` is created but the country value is not saved. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you please share your code which is not working

Comment: please post your code of vf page and controller(if any). For your case you might have to have a controller that takes the user entered value on page and insert an account with country.

Comment: looks like you are using State and Country picklists. Is the value in `{!customobject__c.account__r.billingcountrycode}` defined as the integration value for Countries?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding I tried to replicate your issue and its working fine for me. Please check the VF page and controller below.

**VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="Cntl_VfPage" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputText>Name</apex:outputText>
        <apex:inputText value="{!name}"/>

        <apex:outputText>Country</apex:outputText>
        <apex:inputfield value ="{!a.Billingcountrycode__c}" ></apex:inputfield>

        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Cntl_VfPage {
    public String name {set; get;}
    public Account a {set; get;}

    public Cntl_VfPage() {
        a = new Account();
    }

    public PageReference submit() {
        a.Name = name;
        // system.debug(a.name + ' | ' + a.Billingcountrycode__c);
        insert a;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + a.Id);
        return pageRef;         
    }    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of    `"{!customobject__c.account__r.billingcountrycode}"`
Try to use    `"{!account.billingcountrycode}"`

Of course, if you are using the standard accounts

Comment: No i am not using standard account.

Comment: If you don't want to use a controller, you should work directly with the object   and use    standardController='yourObject'       Because now you are editing the lookup of the object